# How do we trigger a push notification in nodejs manually?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification

I have my service worker installed like the following:

```
self.addEventListener('install', () => {
  console.log('[sw]', 'Your ServiceWorker is installed');
});

self.addEventListener('push', ev => {
  console.log('[sw]', 'pushed!!', ev.data.json());
  const {title, msg, icon} = ev.data.json();
  self.registration.showNotification(title, {
    body: msg,
    icon: icon,
  });
});
```

I can use libraries like `web-push`, which actually fires an `push` event which is captured by service worker and shows a notification on demand (uses `fcm` for example in case of chrome). I just want to understand is there a way in which we can send a `push` notification to the user ourselves from our server, primarily on nodejs?

Can it be done?

Comment: It all depends on how your service worker interacts with the server; but the most basic one would be your service worker doing some sort of socket/long polling/short polling to an endpoint and as soon as something becomes available, trigger the notification to the user. I'd say it is a mix of what you have on the front + what you have on the back + what you need.

Comment: In node, the most common one (at least that I've seen) is socket.io; but you do not really need a web socket for this.